# SQL 15th of the month for Next Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL query to get the 15 of the month for the following year.

Today

```
select getdate() = 2017-08-23 17:05:24.143
```

Looking for: 2018-8-15 00:00:00

I know how to get a year from today:

```
select dateadd(year,1,datediff(day,0,getdate()))
```

I know how to get the beginning of the month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

However I am having trouble combining the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `datefromparts` for SQL Server versions 2012 and above.

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate())+1,month(getdate()),15)
```

Answer (score 2):

Truncate the current day to the start of the month with the code you have, but add 12 months (so, a year), and add 14 days.

```
select dateadd(day,14,dateadd(month, 12+datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(year, 1, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vamsi Prabhala's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vamsi-prabhala) answer deserves to be accepted.

But, you should consider creating a [Calendar Table](https://gist.github.com/noblethrasher/7d541711c3bdb4d91377dddbb757f5f7) because it greatly simplifies working with dates in general.

Here is a pretty simply query that yields the results that you want:

```
    select * from Calendar C where C.year = datepart(year, getdate()) + 1
         and C.day_of_month = 15 and C.month = datepart(m, getdate())
```

[**Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/LYYY37907)

Comment: Thanks for the demo